# (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

Tags: ios, c, pointers, uitabbarcontroller

I've seen this declaration in a tutorial where someone is changing the appearance of the UITabBarController.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

What does the first part after the equal sign do? To be more specific, the

```
(UITabBarController *)
```

By the way, is there some kind of overview of which classes are relevant when changing the UI appearance? I'm having a hard time figuring out when to call what.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [typecast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Other_operators): the `(T)value` operator forces an explicit type conversion from the original type of `value` to the new type `T`.

Comment: Ok, but why does it have to be converted? Can't I create a reference to the tabBarController the "normal" way? Thanks!

Comment: @LinusAn Since the `rootViewController` property of `UIWindow` is a generic `UIViewController` type, you would get a warning without the typecast.

Comment: Ah ok, the fact thats generic explains a lot! Thank you!